# How to add screen Project Quotes in mobile app of Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have tried to add the site map and project quotes screen. but when I publish the project I can't see the screen in the app.
Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
**Add PM304500**
add screen PM304500 {
 add container "Estimation" {
 add field "InventoryID"
 add field "Description"
 add field "Quantity"
 add field "UOM"
 }    
}

**Update MENU**
update sitemap {
 add item "PM304500" {
 displayName = "Project Quotes"
 icon = "system://Box1"
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen definition should not matter as far as getting the screen onto the menu.  You will need it defined to view it once you select the menu option.  Give this a try to see if you get the screen on the menu.

```
update sitemap {
    add folder "Project" {
        type = HubFolder
        isDefaultFavorite = True
        displayName = "Project Quotes"
        icon = "system://Box1"
        add item "PM304500" {
            displayName = "Project Quotes"
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that before you add an item, you add a folder to put it in.  The folder is the top-level object that holds the screen.  Inside the folder is the item, which is the screen.

For further guidance on setting up a screen on the Mobile App, you can check out the training guide on Open University on the Acumatica website.  The training guides you want are listed under *T400* and *T410* in the **Application Development** section.